# NG MODEL is not working in select Angular 14

Tags: angular

```
populateForm(item: Item) {
    this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, item);
    console.log(this.service.formData);
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="GroupID" #GroupID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="itemservice.formData.GroupID">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Group Name</label>
 <select name="GroupID" #GroupID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="itemservice.formData.GroupID" class="form-control">
   <option value="0">-Select-</option>
<option *ngFor="let item of groupList" ngValue ="{{item.GroupID}}">{{item.GroupName}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I have data diplayed here in

<input type="text" name="GroupID" #GroupID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="itemservice.formData.GroupID">

but not in select

Comment: Can you share data model of itemservice.formData

Comment: If you're using the two tags at time, see that you can **not** use the same name nor the same template reference variable. Futhermore, use `[ngValue]="item.groupID"` instead ngValue="{{item.groupID}}". You can also write `{{itemservice.formData|json}}`in your .html to check the value. NOTE: I'm not pretty sure about if is `itemservice` or `service`.

Comment: You have defined in Component a variable named service that have inner property named formData, however in your HTML you are referencing a variable named itemservice, not the same variables. Right?

Comment: resetForm(form?:NgForm){
    if (form != null)
    form.resetForm();
    this.itemservice.formData ={
    GroupID :0,
    ItemID:0,
    Name:'',
    Price:null,
    }

Comment: export class Item {
    GroupID:number;
    ItemID: number;
    Name:string; 
    Price:number;
}

Comment: @Antoniodelamata its same variable.

Cause the data hasbeen displayed input but its not working in select

Comment: @Chellappanவ i have shared model

Comment: As @Eliseo mentioned in the comment you should use this syntax to bind value:[ngValue]="item.groupID"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ngValue` try with `[ngValue]`:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of groupList" [ngValue]="item.GroupID">{{item.GroupName}}</option>
```

It is because you are using `[(ngModel)]` then you have to use `[ngValue]` as a property.